# Calculating total time and end to end delay for datagram packet switching

Tags: lan, throughput

I'm not asking for answers but rather guidance on whether am i doing it right.

The question is as follows:

Consider the transfer of a data file of 10^6 bits from a source to a destination for the following switching network:

- The data rate of the line is 1 Mbps.
- The file is divided into fixed packet size, each of which has a size
  of 4000 bits (including data and header), before transmitting. There
  is 250 bits in the header. If there is not enough data to fill a
  packet, it is filled with zeros before transmission. All frames sent
  have the same size.
- The propagation delay per transmission is 0.002 sec.
- Each packet must be transmitted 7 times before reaching destination.

(i) Determine the number of packets needed to transmit the data file using packet switching.

(ii) Determine the time it takes each host along the path to transmit the entire data file.

(iii) Compute the end to end delay using datagram packet switching.

For part (i), I have calculated the number of packets needed would be 267 packets, however I am having problems with part (ii) and (iii)

For (ii) my calculations are these:

```
Propagation time tp = 0.002 sec
Data rate = 1 x 10^6 bps (1 Mbps)
Packet length = 10^6 bits / 267 + 250 = 3995.318 bits
Packet transmission time td = 3995.318 bits / 1 x 10^6 = 0.003995 sec
Total time = tp + (267 x td) + tp + td = 0.002 sec + (267 x 0.003995 sec) + 0.002 sec + 0.003995 sec = 1.07466 ≈ 1.075 sec
```

I have calculated that it takes 1.075 sec to transmit the entire data file.

However, I did a bit of googling and got a different way of calculation for total transmit time. 
Here is the link, http://www.academia.edu/6835957/Homework_1_Solution_Total_50_Points_Extra_Credit_10_Points_Problem_1_Time_Division_Multiplexing_Points_4

Now I'm confused whether am I'm doing it right.  Should I follow the website for part (iii), too?

Seriously, I need some guidance here  since I'm, new to this module.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to do your own homework.  These types of questions are off-topic here.

Comment: i appreciate your comment on these types of questions being off topic here. But i feel offended by your first sentence. What makes you think this is my homework ? Secondly, what makes you think that i did nothing ? So you mean that if i find questions here that can be found in 'assignments or homeworks' across the world the person would be banned from asking questions ? Here i am trying to understand how the calculation works as i do not have sufficient resources or notes given to answer this particular question. I didn't even ask for answer. Don't assume i am not doing my work dude.

Comment: Since I don't know you or know anything about you, I don't see how you can take offense at anything I say.  The reason I believe your question is "homework" is the way it is written -- the style leads me to believe it is from an exam or textbook.  There are lots of places on the web where you can get help with this and other problems like it.  I might even be one to help you.  But this forum is not the place.